# Reference to html pages in Liferay Portlet

Tags: jsp, liferay

I have created new portlet as *NEWPORTLET*. I want to refer to *TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/doc/html/xyz.html*. When i tried

**jsp:include page="TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/doc/xyz.html"**

it gave me exception that

> NEWPORTLET/TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/doc/xyz.html not found.

In short, whenever i try to refer any other file portlet tries to see in it's directory. Is there any way i can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jquery to overcome this issue.

Added following in view.jsp

```
<div id="displayHtml">
</div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#displayHtml').load('/doc/xyz.html');
        }
        );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that relative paths are relative to your webapplication. If your application is called "doc" (as the /webapps/doc/ path hints), you would just use `<jsp:include page="xyz.html"/>`

Related - though not to your question - if you're really naming your portlet's webapplication "doc", you should rename it to doc-portlet as the "-portlet" part gives Liferay's deployer some additional hints on what to do with your application when it's deployed.

Comment: All jsp's are part of TOMCAT_DIR/temp. Now, no matter what path i give  liferay appends PORTLET_NAME before the link.

Comment: Including arbitrary jsps doesn't work like that. In fact, it might open you up to some security risks (gut feeling). If you want to generate temporary content, you shouldn't save it to random positions on disk and include them, but rather serve the content directly from memory. PORTLET_NAME is the webapplication context and it's rather the servlet standard (and Appserver) that implies that all content is inside of this application, not Liferay.

Comment: okay, so there is no way to point a html page outside of portlet folder structure? If you specify /doc/xyz.html in iframe portlet then it directly search the xyz.html in TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/doc/xyz.html. Can we do the same thing in custome portlet?

Comment: That would be if you just redirect to the html page. If you use jsp:include you're limited to your own webapplication: All the applications are separated from each other. From the "doc" webapplication, you'd refer to xyz.html without any path (or with "/xyz.html") as *everything* is relative to your application. A portlet application is just a webapplication with some extras. You can do everything you can in a webapp, and some more.

Comment: i tried to use jsp:include ; when you use this in portlet it tries to find in it's own direcotory means in its own portlet directory....!!!!!